# Videojs add only play control

Tags: html, html5-video, video.js

I am using `Video.js` to play videos in my web page. 
I want to customize player controls to only play button.

my code is

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>

<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
                    preload="auto" width="320" height="240" poster="thumb.png"
                    data-setup="{}">
                    <source src="v1.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
                    </video>
```

Can any one guide me in player customization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way I have found is modifying the prototype for the class as such.

Insert

```
<script>
    _V_.ControlBar.prototype.options.components = {'playToggle':{}}
</script>
```

right after

```
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
```

This will remove every control ( including the duration, time remaining and seek bar ) besides the play toggle button

If you would like other things, you may pick and choose from the defaults (a few of these are set to hidden on the default skin)

```
options: {
    components: {
        "playToggle": {},
        "fullscreenToggle": {},
        "currentTimeDisplay": {},
        "timeDivider": {},
        "durationDisplay": {},
        "remainingTimeDisplay": {},
        "progressControl": {},
        "volumeControl": {},
        "muteToggle": {}
    }
}
```

Or dig through the controls.js file on git hub 
https://github.com/zencoder/video-js/blob/master/src/controls.js

Comment: im getting `ReferenceError: _V_ is not defined`.  `vjs` is for dev

Comment: you should be able to replace _V_ or vjs with videojs

Comment: Newer versions of videojs require accessing different components via the `getComponent` function. e.g. the script above could be written as:
`videojs.getComponent('ControlBar').prototype.options_.children = ['playToggle'];`

Answer (score 9):

The way I was able to do it was by setting the css class for specific controls to `display: none;` in my page's CSS.  My page's CSS gets linked AFTER the video-js.css gets linked.

```
/* Video.js Controls Style Overrides */
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-progress-control,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-time-controls,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-time-divider,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-captions-button,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-mute-control,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-volume-control,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-fullscreen-control {
    display: none;  
}
```

If you can't link your page's CSS after the video-js.css gets linked, you can use `display: none !important;` instead and that should do the trick.  Although, I'd only use !important as a last resort.

Note: The above does not remove the pause button once play is hit nor the big play button.  There are more UI considerations when removing those.  Hopefully this will help some people with customizing the Video.js control bar.

Comment: Though it's better to disable the JS for the controls according to @b.kelley in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is also an option to hide/show the controlBar items via `data-setup`

The components are listed at 
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/components.md
and the description of options https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/options.md

```
<video data-setup='{ "controls": true, "autoplay": false, "preload": "auto" }'...>
```

the `controlBar` is passed as follows:

```
data-setup='{ "controlBar": { "muteToggle": false } }'
```

Edit: as commented, the behaviour of `children` for `options` has been simplified and changed, see also the documentation: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/guides/options.md#component-options 
For the background and timings of these changes, see https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/953

the css selector for the big play button is

```
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-big-play-button
```

but please make sure you have alternatives or an appropriate setup when you remove the play option (;

mine appears to hide the controls by default(?)

Comment: Thank you @Sandra i am able to manage it by adding custom css to the player.

Comment: You don't have to use these `children` bits any more: `<video ... data-setup='{ "controlBar": { "muteToggle": false } }'></video>`. See: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/options.md#component-options

Answer (score 1):

This also removes all the control bar but not the big play button

```
.vjs-default-skin.vjs-has-started .vjs-control-bar {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to get rid of the play button, and just have the video play and stop on clicking, check out [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh924823%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) alternative solution, which I adapted.

Insert into your `<head>` (or elsewhere if not possible) ...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function vidplay(me) {
       if (me.paused) {
          me.play();
       } else {
          me.pause();
       }
    }
</script>
```

then call from your video, e.g.

```
<video onclick="javascript: vidplay(this)" ...>
```

Make sure that you do not set the controls in your `video` tag. Obviously this way, you can fiddle in your own custom button, which the linked solution does.

Comment: For all you event handler fundamentalists you either know how to do it, or follow [this](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build) :p